# JQuery scroll function issue on IPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone

Im having problems using JQuerys scroll function on the iPhone.

Heres a link to the JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GRnSE/

Ok so I have this effect where when the user scrolls down the content of the header fades out and moves up at half the speed of the scroll.

This all works fine but when I test it on my iPhone it looks like the function dosnt run until after I stop scrolling and remove my finger.

Is it possible to get the function to run whilst the user is scrolling on the iPhone?

Hopefully that all made sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have already found your solution to your issue but,
I think this is an issue with the way iPhones or Apple has their devices handle Javascript (very poorly).  They don't allow animations per say. The stop other Javascript processes while the user is performing a task. This is well documented as an issue all over the web.
I have ran into this issue multiple times.  Dealing with it right now.  Not necessarily a solution to your problem but a bit of explanation.